# Replace existing iOS app with a new app on appstoreConnect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have two apps on Appstore Connect with different app identifiers. One is in the app store while the other is on TestFlight. Is it possible to replace the live app with the one on TestFlight?

Locally these apps are built off the same bundle ID and the app identifier is changed when pushed through Fastlane. They share a signing certificate as well. If I want to replace the live app, do I just need to change the app id for my new app to match the live app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to change the app id and then compile the application that you would like to submit.

Off-course it will replace the old binary of the application. So the code and the UI would be updated accordingly.